# Security across microservices

Tags: spring, spring-security, microservices

I am creating an application with microservices architecture. the problem arises when a public endpoint calls another private endpoint that needs authentication.
To better describe the case .. a microservice **login-service** which have a function allowing the user to enter his email and password .. this function is public which does not require a token, it calls a function of another microservice **account-service** to get the data of the user to validate his login in the microservice **login-service**.
Since the function of the microservice **login** is public, zuul ignores security, but when it calls the function of the microservice **account-service**, the microservice **login** throw this exception (I use feing to call other microservices from a microservice) :

```
feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: status 401 reading AccountProxy#getWebUserByEmail(String,String[])
at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:94) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:86) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:93) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:149) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.getWebUserByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.weryou.backend.login.service.BaseService.findWebUserFromProxyByEmail(BaseService.kt:103) ~[classes/:na]
at com.weryou.backend.login.service.WebUserService.authentication(WebUserService.kt:83) ~[classes/:na]
at com.weryou.backend.login.controller.WebUserController.authentication(WebUserController.kt:43) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:889) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:794) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.M3.jar:5.2.0.M3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

This is my **SecurityConfig** class in zuul.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter()
{
    private val PUBLIC_END_POINTS = arrayOf(
            "/login/*/*/identification"
    )

    @Bean
    fun authFilter() : AuthenticationFilter
    {
        return AuthenticationFilter()
    }


    @Bean
    fun authenticationEntryPoint() : CustomAuthEntryPoint
    {
        return CustomAuthEntryPoint()
    }


    override fun configure(http : HttpSecurity)
    {
        http
            .cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(*PUBLIC_END_POINTS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
            .addFilterBefore(authFilter() , UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .httpBasic().disable()
    }
}
```

The **AuthenticationFilter** class where i implemented the authorization logic, extend from the **OncePerRequestFilter**.
How to avoid this kind of problem? I mean ignoring security in an endpoint that needs authentication when it's called from a public endpoint.

Comment: Does your API endpoints expose to the public through `gateway-api` or `zuul-proxy` or neither ? If neither, you got to orchestrate a secured request inside your `login-service` with the credential details before you make the request to `account-service`. Whatever token or header that expecting by `account-service` should be in that request.

Comment: Yes, i m using zuul as gateway server, and all services pass through zuul.. the SecurityConfig is already implemented in gateway-server (zuul)